# writing a sum of fractions in sigma notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I write this in sigma notation:

$$x_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\text{...}+\frac{1}{2 n}$$

Is it like this:

$$\underset{k=1}{\overset{\frac{1}{2 n}}{\Sigma }} \frac{1}{k+1}$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: Try figuring it out for $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, and see if you can find a pattern. Also, the sigma notation that you wrote doesn't actually make sense—try expanding it out, and you'll see why.